# Postgres: Can only superuser and owner take backup/dump?

Tags: postgresql, dump

So, I have created an user exclusively for taking backup. When I executed the dump command, below error occurred:

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query failed: ERROR:  permission denied for table {{tableName}}
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] query was: LOCK TABLE public.{{tableName}} IN ACCESS SHARE MODE
```

Currently, Owner is `postgres` user for the respective table.

I wish to use an exclusive backup user which has only SELECT access. Below are the privileges to the role assigned to the user

```
CREATE ROLE {{roleName}};
\c {{databaseName}};
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA public TO {{roleName}};
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO {{roleName}};
GRANT SELECT ON ALL SEQUENCES IN SCHEMA mySchema TO {{roleName}};
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO {{roleName}};
```

Comment: You must have made a mistake. Test with an interactive `psql` session if the user can actually read the table.

Comment: Yes. The user is able to read the table.

Comment: Then the error cannot happen. Perhaps you try to pg_dump the wrong database or use a different user.

Answer (score 1):

I have only found in the documentation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/backup-dump.html:

> But remember that pg_dump does not operate with special permissions.
>   In particular, it must have read access to all tables that you want to
>   back up, so in order to back up the entire database you almost always
>   have to run it as a database superuser. (If you do not have sufficient
>   privileges to back up the entire database, you can still back up
>   portions of the database to which you do have access using options
>   such as -n schema or -t table.)

And a very old message in the postgresql mailing list:
https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/18014.1075821674%40sss.pgh.pa.us:

> pg_dump should generally be run by the database superuser.  Anything
>   less creates problems with being unable to dump stuff that doesn't
>   belong to it.

You can try to create a user with less privileges like you did: if pg_dump *and* pg_restore succeed then it should be OK.

Comment: I would like to mention that I'm just trying backup a single table.

Comment: Using a non-superuser is a good idea when it comes to security. Read-only permissions are all that is required. If you hit a permission problem, you will get an error that you can fix. Exceptions are probably `pg_dumpall` (role passwords) and similar things.

Comment: Anyways there is no way to use Non-Superuser to achieve this. I don't know how many developers would be in favor of using Non-Superuser for backups.